# Is it possible to work (install, print etc.) with CANON LBP 810 printer through JetDirect?

Tags: windows-7, printer

I'm fighting with CANON LBP 810 (and 1120) printers for a month..

they work locally fine. However I must work with it through JetDirect.

JetDirect, because I have Thin Clients and I am connecting the printers to the device.

So when I'm trying to install it, (I got official drivers to Windows 7). 
It's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LBP-810 is a GDI or host-based printer, this complicates things. My policy is to only buy printers that support PCL or PostScript so that I don't have this sort of problem.

See [HP Advisory](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=bpj05167) for JetDirect which has some workarounds (for Centronics/Parallel connected printers not USB?)

Canon's support page for the LBP-810 suggests a specific model Axis print-server (instead of JetDirect)

Comment: the LBP 810 and LBP 1120 are USB printers (not sure if they have parallel ports) I can use USB only.

Comment: @bakyn: then it probably can't be used with a HP JetDirect box. Canon say "The LBP-810 can also be connected to a LAN network with the AXIS 1610 network adapter". AXIS say the 1610 supports Canon's CAPT protocol.